# Oracle Query Performance Optimization

Tags: sql, oracle12c, sqlperformance, sql-tuning

I am currently working on optimizing the below query and it's taking more than 60 minutes to run. The dates provided in the query is substituted from variables which calculate the date during execution. The goal is for this query to run within 10 minutes.

```
SELECT
   clm.clcl_payee_pr_id, 
   clm.sbsb_ck, 
   clm.clcl_id, 
   clm.meme_ck, 
   clm.clcl_paid_dt, 
   Row_number() 
     OVER ( 
       ORDER BY clm.clcl_payee_pr_id, clm.sbsb_ck, clm.clcl_id) AS reccount
FROM cmc_mepe_prcs_elig MEPE 
INNER JOIN cmc_meme_member MEME 
        ON MEPE.meme_ck = MEME.meme_ck 
           AND MEPE.grgr_ck = '41' 
INNER JOIN cmc_mepr_prim_prov MEPR 
        ON MEPE.meme_ck = MEPR.meme_ck 
           AND MEPR.grgr_ck = '41' 
INNER JOIN cmc_sbsb_subsc SBSB 
        ON MEME.sbsb_ck = SBSB.sbsb_ck 
           AND SBSB. grgr_ck = '41' 
INNER JOIN cmc_prpr_prov PROV 
        ON MEPR.prpr_id = PROV.prpr_id 
INNER JOIN cmc_prer_relation PRER 
        ON PRER.prpr_id = MEPR.prpr_id 
           AND PRER.prer_prpr_entity = 'I' 
           AND PRER.prer_prpr_id IN ( '02549455' ) 
INNER JOIN cmc_clcl_claim CLM 
        ON MEME.meme_ck = CLM.meme_ck 
           AND CLM.clcl_prpr_id_pcp = MEPR.prpr_id 
INNER JOIN cmc_prpr_prov PRPR 
        ON CLM.prpr_id = PRPR.prpr_id 
INNER JOIN cmc_plds_plan_desc PLDS 
        ON MEPE.cspi_id = PLDS.cspi_id 
INNER JOIN cmc_pdds_prod_desc PDDS 
        ON MEPE.pdpd_id = PDDS.pdpd_id 
WHERE  MEPE.mepe_elig_ind = 'Y' 
AND CLM.clcl_low_svc_dt BETWEEN MEPE.mepe_eff_dt AND MEPE.mepe_term_dt 
AND CLM.clcl_low_svc_dt BETWEEN MEPR.mepr_eff_dt AND MEPR.mepr_term_dt 
AND CLM.clcl_cur_sts = '02' 
AND CLM.clcl_cl_type = 'M' 
AND CLM.clcl_cl_sub_type = 'H' 
AND CLM.grgr_ck IN ( 41 ) 
AND ( PLDS.plds_desc LIKE '%risk%' OR PDDS.pdds_desc LIKE '%risk%' ) 
AND CLM.clcl_paid_dt BETWEEN  '24-APR-19 12.00.00.000000 AM' AND '30-APR-19 11.59.59.997000 PM';
```

Below are the total number of rows for each of the tables used.

- cmc_mepe_prcs_elig: 103,974,973
- cmc_meme_member: 22,433,154
- cmc_mepr_prim_prov: 53,498,452
- cmc_sbsb_subsc: 22,433,154
- cmc_prpr_prov: 5,266,062
- cmc_prer_relation: 4,735,086
- cmc_clcl_claim: 897,405,800
- cmc_plds_plan_desc: 19,122
- cmc_pdds_prod_desc: 4,776

All these tables reside in a master database, which is read only and I am not allowed to create any indexes to improve the performance. The only option is to use hints and play around with the query. Below is the current execution plan for the query above.

[image]

I am a novice when it comes to performance tuning and would appreciate if you could let me know if I should provide any other info regarding the tables, for you to make a suggestion on tuning the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try below. In general you can think about optimization like i will explain:

- Try to avoid `OR` and `LIKE` statements if it is possible.
- When you constructed a join you should not interact more than two tables.( CLM is joining with MEME and MEPR at the same time. IF you need to join these 3 tables try adding another join with another alias like CLM2 then join this new alias with other table.)

```
SELECT CLM.CLCL_PAYEE_PR_ID,
       CLM.SBSB_CK,
       CLM.CLCL_ID,
       CLM.MEME_CK,
       CLM.CLCL_PAID_DT,
       ROW_NUMBER ()
          OVER (ORDER BY CLM.CLCL_PAYEE_PR_ID, CLM.SBSB_CK, CLM.CLCL_ID)
          AS RECCOUNT
  FROM CMC_MEPE_PRCS_ELIG MEPE
       INNER JOIN CMC_PLDS_PLAN_DESC PLDS ON MEPE.CSPI_ID = PLDS.CSPI_ID
       INNER JOIN CMC_PDDS_PROD_DESC PDDS ON MEPE.PDPD_ID = PDDS.PDPD_ID
       INNER JOIN CMC_MEME_MEMBER MEME
          ON MEPE.MEME_CK = MEME.MEME_CK AND MEPE.GRGR_CK = '41'
       INNER JOIN CMC_SBSB_SUBSC SBSB
          ON MEME.SBSB_CK = SBSB.SBSB_CK AND SBSB.GRGR_CK = '41'
       INNER JOIN CMC_MEPR_PRIM_PROV MEPR
          ON MEPE.MEME_CK = MEPR.MEME_CK AND MEPR.GRGR_CK = '41'
       INNER JOIN CMC_PRPR_PROV PROV ON MEPR.PRPR_ID = PROV.PRPR_ID
       INNER JOIN CMC_PRER_RELATION PRER
          ON PRER.PRPR_ID = MEPR.PRPR_ID AND PRER.PRER_PRPR_ENTITY = 'I'
       INNER JOIN CMC_PRPR_PROV PRPR ON CLM.PRPR_ID = PRPR.PRPR_ID
       INNER JOIN CMC_CLCL_CLAIM CLM
          ON     MEME.MEME_CK = CLM.MEME_CK
--             AND CLM.CLCL_PRPR_ID_PCP = MEPR.PRPR_ID
 WHERE     MEPE.MEPE_ELIG_IND = 'Y'
       AND CLM.CLCL_LOW_SVC_DT BETWEEN MEPE.MEPE_EFF_DT AND MEPE.MEPE_TERM_DT
       AND CLM.CLCL_LOW_SVC_DT BETWEEN MEPR.MEPR_EFF_DT AND MEPR.MEPR_TERM_DT
       AND CLM.CLCL_CUR_STS = '02'
       AND CLM.CLCL_CL_TYPE = 'M'
       AND CLM.CLCL_CL_SUB_TYPE = 'H'
       AND CLM.GRGR_CK IN (41)
--       AND (PLDS.PLDS_DESC LIKE '%risk%' OR PDDS.PDDS_DESC LIKE '%risk%')
       AND CLM.CLCL_PAID_DT BETWEEN '24-APR-19 12.00.00.000000 AM'
                                AND '30-APR-19 11.59.59.997000 PM'
       AND PRER.PRER_PRPR_ID = '02549455';
```

Comment: Thanks for you the suggestion. I can't change the LIKE clause in the query as that is an essential condition. I will try though if I can achieve the same result by creating a stage/temp table.